# How to restore all environment variables to default in a batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a .bat script. It runs some commands and alters/adds some environment variables. Then, at some point I need to revert them all to default as if I'm exiting this script and starting a new one from scratch.
So, I need one of the two:
1. either clear the variables (restore defaults that a fresh `cmd` session gets);
2. or `push` all the variables when I start the script and `pop` later to revert to these values.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried using SETLOCAL? Here is some information on it: http://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried?

```
  reset:
    set "var=%var*=%"
```